# How long can static charge stay on a material?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, material-science

When a material/body gets charged, the charge can be discharged by conduction. What if the charged body is place in a vacuum where the charge can't be discharges through air, how long can the charge stay on the body?

I just got curious to know the answer and I can't come up with any.

Comment: Hint: what are the possible ways to remove charge from some entity?

Comment: I guess that the only way is conduction. If the charged body is isolated for any conducting materials including air(moisture), the charge should be held by the body for infinite period of time. Is that correct?